# How to play 2 keys at the same time with autohotkey

Tags: autohotkey

Basically, I am trying to make a combo macro where it does the combo for you, the problem is I don't know how to make the program press 2 keys at once.
**V Script I have Below V**

```
t::
{
Sendinput {click}
Sleep 350
Sendinput {click}
Sleep 350
Sendinput {click}
Sleep 350
Sendinput {click}
Sleep 150
Sendinput {4}
Sleep 4700
Sendinput {click}
Sleep 150
}
return
```

To do an uptilt in a combo you need to hold the spacebar and click simultaneously on your 4th mouse with 1 click. However, I do not know how to achieve this

Comment: Try `Sendinput {Space Down}{click}{Space Up}`

Comment: This is not working unfortunately. I need it to hold space down while it's clicking then after it clicks space is released.

Comment: @user3419297's script should do it, but here is an alternative if that didn't work: `Sendinput {Space Down}{LButton Down}{LButton Up}{Space Up}`